# Show$d : x, y \in E \to \|x − y\|_E$ is a distance on $E$ and every open ball is the image of the unit ball under an affine map then check closure.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

A norm $\| · \|$ $E$ on a $\Bbb R$-vector space E is a function from E to [0, ∞) such that:

1. $\forall x \in E$ we have $\|x\|_E =0 \iff x=0$,
2. $\forall x\in E$and$ \ λ \in \Bbb R$ we have $\|λx\|_E |λ\|x\|_E$
3. $\forall x,y\in E$ we have $\|x+y\|_E \le \|x\|_E+\|y\|_E$.

Check that $d : x, y \in E  \to \|x − y\|_E$ is a distance on E, and prove that every open ball in E for this metric is the image of the open unit ball (i.e. the open ball of center 0 and radius 1) by some affine map (linear + translation). Then check that the closure of the open ball of center x and radius r is the closed ball of center x and radius r.

Distance because

1) $\|x − y\|_E = 0 \iff x=y \implies x-y = 0, \checkmark \\ \text{2)} 
    \| x - y\| _E = \|(-1)(y-x)\|_E = \mid -1 \mid \| y-x\|_E = \|y-x\|_E \text{ by 2 above} \, \checkmark \\
   \text{3} \|x-y\|_E \le \|x\|_E + \mid -1\mid \|y\|_E = \|x\|_E + \|y\|_E  \text{ by 3 & 2 above}\, \checkmark$

So it is a distance.

Now, $\forall x,y \in E$ we can find an open ball as such $\|x-y\| < r$ where $r$ is the radius, such one ball is $B(x,r)$ centered at $x$ with radius $r$

Having trouble defining the affine map.

It should be such $f:E \to E$ defined by $x \mapsto \lambda x + C$ so a scaling and a translation. I want $x$ to translate/scale to a point within the open unit ball.

Will check closure once I have the mapping

edit: since we have the distance checked.

$\forall x,c \in E\, \exists r  $ s.t. $\| x - c \| < r$ so define the mapping as $\displaystyle x \mapsto \frac{1}{r}(x - c)$ because then $\|\frac{1}{r}(x-c) \|< 1$

Edit (2) : I realized I am doing it wrong, I am defining my map from an open ball to the unit open ball but it should be the opposite. So Perhaps:

$\varphi : E \to E$ where $0 \mapsto x $ but now how to handle the radius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prove that $B(x,r)=x+rB(0,1)$. This means that $B(x,r)$ is the image of $B(0,1)$ under the affine map $y\mapsto x+ry$.

On the other hand, if $\overline{B}(x,r)$ is the closed ball, it is clear $\overline{B(x,r)}\subseteq \overline{B}(x,r)$, since $\overline{B}(x,r)$ is a closed subset containing the open ball (this is true in every metric space).

We will prove $\overline{B}(x,r)\subseteq \overline{B(x,r)}$. Equivalently, for all $v\in \overline{B}(x,r)$ and $\delta >0$ we have $B(v,\delta)\cap B(x,r)\neq \emptyset$. It suffices to do this when $\delta < 2r$.

Now, show that the point

$$v+\dfrac{\delta}{2r}(x-v)$$

lies in $B(v,\delta)\cap B(x,r)$.